# What is the difference between using package-lock.json or shadow.cljs.build-report to track changes in dependencies?

Tags: dependency-management, clojurescript, package-lock.json, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command `cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, choosing `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the building option.

Currently, the project faces a *reproducibility crisis*. It is hard to know which dependencies are being changed on the project. In addition, every developer has their own local development environment. Things get even worse because this "mess" can even happen in a deployed environment since it depends on the machine that is doing the deployment (there is no CI/CD, deploys are manual).

It would be important to understand why/how/when/which dependencies were changed after every release.

There is an interesting command called `shadow-cljs shadow.cljs.build-report` (see [documentation](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#build-report)). It can be executed with  `npx shadow-cljs run shadow.cljs.build-report`. This command builds a report showing the dependency tree as raw HTML.

One idea would be to keep the output of this command under version control and use `git diffs` to check the differences.

But, one co-worker said that `package-lock.json` already does that (see [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json)). Hence, I started to wonder the differences between the two.

I can see **at least** one: the HTML file outputted by `shadow.cljs.build-report` renders nicely in a web browser, as a consequence, it feels better for human readbility.

Is there another difference? What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build Reports only **report** build information. It does list all the dependencies used with version but it does not **lock** them. Thereby it doesn't contribute to build reliability, it only serves as a control.

**You should keep the `package-lock.json` to version control.** It is used by `npm install` to ensure that every time you run it all the same versions get installed. See the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json).

Without the lockfile `npm install` will install packages in non-deterministic ways. Unfortunately most npm packages use version ranges to declare dependencies. So, without lock files you can never be sure which version you'll actually get.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you nudge people to use it on build-hooks of shadow-cljs.edn? What do you like about this command considering the existence of package-lock.json?

Comment: I do not nudge people to use it as a build hook. It is provided as a convenience for people that want to create build reports automatically. Build reports still just serve to report information about your build. In no way is that related to what package-lock.json does. That doesn't tell you what ended up in your build or how large it was. A package is not automatically included in a build only because it is installed.